# C# Gembox Spreadsheet - Read cell value which references to another excel file

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I am working with GemBox Spreadsheet now to read Excel file using C#. In the Excel file, there is cell contains Date value which refers to another excel file.

[image: The Excel Cell Formula Screenshot]

In the C#, at first, I got zero value. Based on the [GemBox Retrieving Calculated Values From a Spreadsheet or Flexcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395151/gembox-retrieving-calculated-values-from-a-spreadsheet-or-flexcel?rq=1) post, I replaced the Load method into `XlsxOptions.PreserveMakeCopy`. After replacing, I got some random value, like 43257, instead of Date value. I am not sure what value it is.

[image: C# debug value]

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void Export()
{

    SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense(FileExport.GemBoxLicenseKey);
    ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile();
    FileExport file = new FileExport();
    ef.LoadXlsx(locationPath + "\\XX.xlsx", GemBox.Spreadsheet.XlsxOptions.PreserveMakeCopy);

    ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets[0];

    try
    {
        int trackrowcount = 0;
        int columncounter = 1;
        DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;

        foreach (ExcelRow row in ws.Rows)
        {
            trackrowcount += 1;

            if (trackrowcount < 4)
                continue;

            columncounter = 1;

            foreach (ExcelCell cell in row.AllocatedCells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                    if (trackrowcount == 4 && columncounter == 2)
                    {
                        var cellFormula = cell.Formula;
                        var cellValue = cell.Value;

                        //Here is where I am trying to get the date value
                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue);
                    }
                }
                columncounter += 1;
            }
        }
        // and so on
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any setting that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting date in `OADate` format in datatype `double`. You have to convert it back in `DateTime` Format.

```
double dateValue = 43257;
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(dateValue);
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks!

Comment: @NofyaTriyani you shouldn't need to do that conversion, the cell.Value should contain a DateTime object in the first place. Can you send me a link to your "XX.xlsx" file so that I can download it and check it out? Also, I see you're using an old version of GemBox.Spreadsheet, have you tried with a newer version?